# Secure and select hierarchical data in Google FireStore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to model data in Google Firestore so that when the user request for a long operation to be done I'll create a document and I'll add results to that document's sub-collection as the operation progress. This way the client (an Android app in this case) will be able to listen to changes on that documented created before the long operation started and once that document will change (let's say I'll update a `status` field to `"done"`) I'll query the sub-collection of that document to get the results.

Let's say the root document will be `/frame-refresh-requests/{req-id}` and the document will look like

```
{
 uid: "123",
 status: "in-progress"
}
```

My question is how to secure the sub-collection documents in a way I'll be able to listen for `onSnapshot` on the sub-collection documents?

My current solution is to duplicate the `uid` fiedld to each document in the sub-collection, is that a good idea?

My current security rule looks like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /frame-refresh-requests/{refresh_doc_id} {
    
      function isAllowedToReadRefresh() {
        return resource.data.device_id == request.auth.uid;
      }
      
      allow read: if isAllowedToReadRefresh();
      
      match /streams/{doc_id} {
        allow read: if isAllowedToReadRefresh();
      }
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
}
```

In this way, I have to add `device_id` field to all the documents to be able to allow to filter them according to the user id in order to be able to select multiple documents.

I'm not worried about denormalizing the data, I'm trying to understand if there is a better way.

Comment: Please edit the question with some more detail about what your current security rules look like, and what your specific security requirements are for the subcollections.  What you're saying right now is a bit too vague to understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Security rules aren't meaningful without knowing the client queries that should be allowed or rejected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate the device_id field in each document in the subcollection, that's not necessarily "bad".  Data duplicate in nosql type databases is very common.  However, it's not required in this case.  Security rules can [use the data in other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) as part of their evaluation.  You can simply [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) the parent document and use its data as needed in the rules for any subcollections.

```
      match /streams/{doc_id} {
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/frame-refresh-requests/$(refresh_doc_id)).data.device_id == request.auth.uid;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Few things:
1. if I do that I'll need to change my rule to `/frame-refresh-requests/{refresh_doc_id}/{document=**}` to capture all sub-collection documents, right?
2. for some reason when I use the following rule I always get `Missing or insufficient permissions` error.

`    match /frame-refresh-requests/{refresh_doc_id}/{document=**} {
    
     allow read: if request.auth.token.isDevice == true &&
         get(/databases/{database}/documents/frame-refresh-requests/{refresh_doc_id}).data.device_id == request.auth.uid;
    }`